# How to fix 'The included URLconf 'gp.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it'

Tags: django

when i tried to write the first urlpattern and the first view, i got this error, so i can be able to access to the authentification template, i have no idea what can be the source of this error

```
# my gp/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
# my views.py
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request,'gp/index.html')
```

when i try to run the server this is the error i get

> raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
>   'gp.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid
>   patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular
>   import.

this is my program tree

gp

- apps

  - conge
  - organisation
  - personnel
  - stage
- gp

  - pycache
  - **init**.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - wsgi.py
- static
- templates

  - gp

    - index.html
- db.sqlte3
- manage.py

Comment: Your file is named `utls.py`, not `urls.py`.

Comment: yes my file is named urls.py, i just a little mistake

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: How is this being included? Show the main urls.py.

Comment: i use Django 2.2.3

Comment: this is the main utls.py

Comment: Is there anything else in the stack trace?

Comment: if you are using +2.0 then no need to use `url()`, you can simply use path as admin did, and without `r'^$'`,just `''`

Comment: thank you moha for the information, but the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# my gp/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

```py
# my views.py
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request,'gp/index.html', {})
```

what i edited is:

- instead of `from django.conf.urls import url` i wrote `from
  django.urls import path`
- added {} in render function (its optional but just in case :) )

Comment: Just to give some context to this answer, Django 2.0 introduced a new, simplified syntax for `urls.py` files. Instead of using `url()` with a regex pattern, you can now use the simplified `path()` syntax. The former `url()` syntax has been mapped to `re_path` (short for Regular Expression path). The documentation is here for Django 2.x: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30728#no1

Maybe try to use latest Python version. Python 3.9 able to work